# How to Make widget area on place of comment

Tags: widgets

I want to make a widget
First I registered widget area in functions.php

```
register_widget(array(
    'name' => 'widget',
    'description' => 'Sidebar below single post',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>'
));
```

and then how to show widget

[Here](http://www.zeequotes.com/) is an example of web site i.e using widget instead of comments

Answer (score 0):

You should place this code into the file which is responsible for showing page (or kind of pages). Bracket with ' ' consist name of widget you have registered. It will call function from functions.php

```
 <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'widget' ) ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'widget' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Best Regards